# javascript - Making the actual number box value match the HTML value="" attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to increase the HTML value="" of a number box to whatever the user inputs in a form so that when at the end everything is added up, the correct value is entered.  The function I have that fires whenever the user increases the number box is:

```
function orderChange() {
    event.target.value = event.target.value++;
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

and this logs the correct number in console.  However, it does not update the HTML "value" attribute to its new value.  What is the correct way to make what the user has entered in the HTML number box reflect the value attribute in the HTML markup?

EDIT: HTML below

```
<input type="number" size="5" value="0" onchange="orderChange()" max="5" />
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML to your question, please?

Comment: You haven't declared `event`, and you'll either want `event.target.value + 1` or `++event.target.value` on the rhs of the assignment

Comment: How do you mean declare event? Sorry for the stupid question, new at this JavaScript stuff :]

Answer (score 0):

Without any plugins, you could assign an ID to your element and:

```
document.getElementById('myID').value = newVal;
```

EDIT:

here's a minimal working example:

```
<html>
    <input type="number" id="derp"/>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('derp').value = 5;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be the code to make "newVal" just increment the existing value by one?

Comment: in your case, `newVal` is `event.target.value + 1`

Comment: Oh I misread your question. You can do `document.getElementById('myID').value += 1`

Comment: I'm looking to create a function that means that every time a user changes the value of a number box, the HTML code itself also updates.

Comment: You can do something like this in your onchange function: `document.getElementById('derp').setAttribute('value', document.getElementById('derp').value);`

Though why you're so fixated on doing that is beyond me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't like the design: a user inputs a value, you overwrite it automatically. 1) Below should work but I don't suggest this.value=event.target.value++; 2) You can also write like this:

```
function orderChange(obj) {
    var c=parseInt(obj.value);
    updateme(obj,c++);
}

function updateme(obj,c){
    obj.value=c;
}
Then onchange="orderChange(this)"
```

Comment: It's still not updating the actual HTML code - is this even possible?

Comment: if You make sure your browser support type=number, it will work. But you know, type=number only works for some users, not a good design any way

Comment: If you are looking at the "view source" view, you're (probably) seeing what was sent from the server, not the updated DOM.  Try putting this: `http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php` in the action= attribute of your form and see what you get.

Edited to add: I'm pretty sure an HTML5 number spinner will send what you want.  Try the "formtest" link without the JS and See What Happens(tm).

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this comment: If you are looking at the "view source" view, you're (probably) seeing what was sent from the server, not the updated DOM. Try putting this: http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php in the action= attribute of your form and see what you get. Edited to add: I'm pretty sure an HTML5 number spinner will send what you want. Try the "formtest" link without the JS and See What Happens(tm).

Another commenter said, "'splain better."  I'm not sure whether that was aimed at me or not, but here goes.

"View source" appears to be exactly that: the source as served by the, *erm*, server, and not the DOM as it may have been changed on the client.  There are debugging tools that can be beaten into displaying the latter.  I like Firebug in Firefox or the developer tools in Chrome.

The questioner is using `<input type="number">` which is an HTML5 construct.  It will do what the book says, namely transmit the selected number, without help from JavaScript.  It almost certainly will *not* update what one sees in "view source."

I am a college teacher, and I wrote the code at http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php to help my students.  It just echoes back what it sees.  Feel free to use it to test, but do not come to depend on it.  Our college is being merged into a much larger institution.

I disagree that using HTML5 is necessarily bad.   If everyone keeps accommodating IE6, it'll never go away.  That said, if one is trying to sell stuff, one needs to be careful; an unsupported browser might be a lost sale.  `type="number` will be rendered as a text box on browsers that do not support that bit of HTML5, which might be OK.

Sorry you asked?  (If you did ask?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to everyone who helped me out.

After some trial and error and taking elements of the other answers I got through here, I eventually found it was actually deceptively simple..  So just for anyone else's future reference, here's what solved my problem.

```
function orderChange(event) {
this.value = event.target.value;
console.log(this.value)
}
```

This successfully took the value from the number box that initiated the event, and then logged the correct value to console.

Can't load the corresponding HTML for some reason - I think stack overflow's trying to run it... But anyway all I did was add an onchange event to the number box that calls the orderChange(event) function.